# SQL error - Must declare the table variable "@tablename"

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, variables, stored-functions

How to create variable inside in function and select data from table?
When I tried to create this function I get error:

> Must declare the table variable "@tablename"

this is my function:

```
create function FunctionName (@val1 INT , @val2 INT)

RETURNS @result TABLE
(
Name1 nvarchar(100) not null,
Name2 nvarchar(100) not null,
Name3 nvarchar(100) not null,
Name4 nvarchar(100) not null,
)

AS
BEGIN
    DECLARE @tablename nvarchar(max)
    SET @tablename = CONCAT('Export_Pivot_',@val1,'_',@val2)    
    INSERT into @result
SELECT 
name1,name2,name3,name4
FROM  @tablename

RETURN
END
```

Comment: Can you not have `DECLARE @tablename nvarchar(max) = CONCAT('Export_Pivot_',@val1,'_',@val2)`?

Comment: still error Must declare the table variable "@tablename".

Comment: when i put name of tabel it is working but when i want to get name dynamically it is not working

Comment: FROM  Export_Pivot_2018_10 - working

Comment: FROM @tablename - not working

Comment: You *can't* use a parameter instead of a table name. There's no way around this. Tables in SQL are similar to types in strongly typed languages. Queries are compiled to execution plans based on the table schema, indexes, statistics that change from table to table and even over time.

Comment: Change your sql query to dynamic sql query
What is dynamic query :
https://www.essentialsql.com/build-dynamic-sql-stored-procedure/

Answer (score 2):

Table names in statements can't be variables - you have to create some dynamic SQL as a string, then execute it.
You also need to populate your select into the `@result` table.

There are also too many commas in your table declaration.

Try this:

```
create function FunctionName (@val1 int , @val2 int)
    RETURNS @result TABLE
    (
    Name1 nvarchar(100),
    Name2 nvarchar(100),
    Name3 nvarchar(100),
    Name4 nvarchar(100)
    )
    AS
    BEGIN
        exec('SELECT name1,name2,name3,name4 FROM ' + 'Export_Pivot_'+@val1+'_'+@val2 + ' into @result');
    RETURN
    END
    go
```

Comment: One would need to use a stored procedure since one cannot execute dynamic SQL in a function. Consider testing your code before posting as an answer.